# How can I match a string with brackets and apostrophes in sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to match and replace the following string:

```
<%=  host_env %><%= host_tenant_id %>.<%= domain_name %>/<%= products['as']['server_context_worker']  %>
```

Any ideas?  I've tried:

```
<%=  host_env %><%= host_tenant_id %>\.<%= domain_name %>\/<%= products\['as'\]\['server_context_worker'\]  %>
```

and lot's of variations of it, but I haven't had any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match bracket in `sed` using character classes (i.e. the square brackets themselves). In your example you can do:

```
$sed -e 's/[[].*[]]/{something new}/' < sedbrackets.txt
<%=  host_env %><%= host_tenant_id %>.<%= domain_name %>/<%= products{something new}  %>
```

Drop a comment if that isn't the substitution you are looking for. It was a bit unclear from your question. Of course you can use them as many times as your like. I just used them once with `.*` in between as an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a different delimiter for the match string, you should only need to escape the brackets and the period.

```
sed "s|<%=  host_env %><%= host_tenant_id %>.<%= domain_name %>/<%= products\['as'\]\['server_context_worker'\]  %>|Replacement Text|" <file>
```